# Why does traceback.print_exc create a blank output for a sent email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

The msg value simply displays a blank message rather in e-mail rather than the full error message I am wanting to be sent.  I have tried other variations of errors including: `traceback.format_exc()`, however the email output is always blank.

```
msg = (traceback.print_exc())
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
```

Comment: `print_exc` will return `None` unconditionally (as `print` does), `format_exc` should return the string `print_exc` prints or `'NoneType: None\n'` if nothing is being handled. In short, edit your question and provide something we can reproduce.

Comment: Check if `server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, None)` output is blank or 'None'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still looking why, but for some reason the colon `:` in the message is not accepted in the first line, an ugly workaround is to replace it :

```
msg = traceback.format_exc().replace(':','=>',1) # only the first, to not alter the traceback
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
```

Comment: I got an email of "NoneType None". That doesn't look at all like console.

Comment: this assignment needs to be in the block where you handle the error, otherwise there is no traceback

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like traceback.format_exc() instead of print_exec.